# Moodle and .NET application

Tags: .net, moodle, moodle-api

Does anyone know how to connect .NET app with Moodle? Is it even possible for a .NET application to integrate with Moodle? Is there any API for Moodle?

I've looked everywhere, but I can't find any clarification anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any external app can connect to Moodle via Web Services

There is a step by step guide to set up web services via

Site admin > Server > Web services > Overview

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Using_web_services

You can see a list of API functions here - After enabling the web services documentation

Site admin > Server > Web services > API Documentation

Or here

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions

Then use a protocol (eg REST) to call the API function

```
curl "https://your.site.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=...&wsfunction=...&moodlewsrestformat=json"
```

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client

Comment: Does the administrator have to make settings on Moodle or can it be done with an ordinary account? @RussellEngland

Comment: An admin or anyone with the `moodle/site:config` capability - the API can alter and delete records, so it needs high level authority